# HTML frameset vertical scrolling doesn't work on IE8?

Tags: html, scroll, frameset

i need to do a frameset with HTML and I'm seeing that **vertical scroll** doesn't show on IE8, but it works perfect in Firefox.

Why vertical scroll doesn't work on IE? what can I do for do it works like in Firefox?

The code is this:

```
<frameset rows="121,*" cols="*" framespacing="3" frameborder="yes" border="3" bordercolor="#009933">
  <frame src="arriba.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize >

  <frameset rows="*" cols="135,*" framespacing="3" frameborder="yes" border="3" bordercolor="#009933">
    <frame src="izquierda.html" name="leftFrame" scrolling="YES" noresize>
    <frame src="centro.html" name="mainFrame" scrolling="YES" noresize>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

the scrolling="yes" from izquierda.html and cenhtro.html doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 has problems with scrolling="yes". Use css instead, applied to the body tag of centro.html and izquierda.html:

```
<style type="text/css">
body  {
  overflow: scroll;
  /* In IE and CSS 3 you can even use these: */
  overflow-x: scroll;  /* Horizontal */
  overflow-y: scroll;  /* Vertical */
}

</style>
```

I think I don't need to add that you shouldn't be using a frame layout at all.

Comment: @Karel Petranek: I'm working on centos. Scroll bar is not working in mozila and chrome browser. How can do it?